# How can I insert an array of objects into my realm database with react native?

Tags: react-native, realm

I have a Realm db model as follow :

```
export const JourneyStateSchema = {
    name : JOURNEY_STATE_SCHEMA,
    primaryKey: 'lvlNumber',    
    properties: {       
        lvlNumber: {type : 'int'},
        stateWords: {type : 'data'},
        words: {type : 'data'},
        answers: {type : 'data'},
        hints: {type : 'data?'},
    }
};
```

When I want to insert into that, I get this error :
JourneySchema.stateWords must be of type 'binary', got 'object'

I neet to insert arrays of objects ito that, how can I manage that?

my insert model is as follow:

```
let model = {
  lvlNumber : this.lvlNumber,
  stateWords : this.state.words,//==>Array of objects
  words : this.words,//==>Array of objects
  answers : this.answers,//==>Array of objects
  hints : this.hints//==>Array of objects
 }
 insertToJourney(model).then(()=>{
 console.log(`inserted ${model} in db`)                        
 }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
 })
```

Also here is a sample of my 'stateWords' data :

```
stateWords = [
  {"value": "china", "solution": "26|36|46|56|66" , "letters" : [
    {"letter" : "c" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "h" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "i" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "n" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "a" , "find" : false},
  ]},
  {"value": "germany", "solution": "23|33|43|53|63|73|83" , "letters" : [
    {"letter" : "g" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "e" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "r" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "m" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "a" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "n" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "y" , "find" : false},
  ]},
  {"value": "france", "solution": "35|45|55|65|75|85" , "letters" : [
    {"letter" : "f" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "r" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "a" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "n" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "c" , "find" : false},
    {"letter" : "e" , "find" : false},   
  ]}
]
```

and here is my insertToJourney function :

```
export const insertToJourney =  (item) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Realm.open(databaseOptions).then(realm => {
        realm.write(()=>{
            realm.create(JOURNEY_STATE_SCHEMA, item);
            resolve(item);
        })
    }).catch((error) => reject(error));
});
```

Comment: Hii, did you find any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I did a trick, First I convert my array to text with JSON.stringfy
and save that in my database , after that when I get data from db I convert it again to array with JSON.parse . this worked for me because I had small amount of data

Comment: ohh, okay. Unfortunately I can't do that. My app is heavily data driven. But as mentioned in [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/836) is this the only way of inserting in realm by looping through the whole array?.